# Spring @Transactional makes problems in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm, playframework

I have a Play project in which I am using the following method with a spring @Transactional annotation:

```
@Autowired
Home home;

@Transactional
public Result update() {
    try {
        JsonNode jsonNode = request().body().asJson();
        User user = home.updateFromJsonString(jsonNode.toString());
        return ok("Updated successfully.");
    } catch (Exception e){
        return badRequest("Error updating");
    }
}
```

The updateFromJsonString method is located in another project, where it changes a sql table using hibernate. The problem is that this 'update' method works fine when the @Transactional annotation is missing, but when it is there I get the following exception:

```
[error] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper - Duplicate entry '1-10' for key 'PRIMARY'
[error] play - Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.
exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

Any idea what is the problem, and why the @Transactional could make this error?

Comment: Well, you have a constraint violation exception which means you dont pass enough data to update method.

Comment: or you want update entity which was detached from hibernate session. In this case you have to fetch this entity in exact the same session and update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you load an entity, so it becomes managed by Hibernate, For this reason, any changes happening while the Session is open are intercepted by the [dirty checking mechanism](http://vladmihalcea.com/the-anatomy-of-hibernate-dirty-checking/) and propagated to the database upon [flushing](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpahibernate-flush-strategies/) the Hibernate `Session`.

I suspect you add a new child to a one-to-many collection which already contains that child entity.

Comment: How can I solve it without flushing manually? I need the program to stay 'transactional' so that no changed occur in case of a problem.